# Samsung galaxy S4 Blacked out Screen need to retreive files

Tags: lock-screens, samsung-galaxy-s-4

Anyone know how to get photos/files from a galaxy 4 that has a broken / blacked out screen - Ive tried every method possible ive read online and im getting no-were and ready to scream ...I cant seem to unlock the screen to allow a computer to extract files - Ive pluged the phone into multiple computers it wont read the phone...ive tried the Kies Program...the Samsung recovery system - can I plug the phone into something and see the screen separate from the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Your phone can be turned on and off? Your pc recognize your phone by making any sound?
You don't say what caused your phone screen to break but anyway you can try to do an ADB recovery or an nand backup just google for if and you find many tutorials

Comment: I can hear it turn on and off ...I dropped the phone and the LCD broke Im not sure if a ADB recovery would work....does the technology exist to plug into the phone ...mirror the screen and get what I need

Comment: The ADB recovery will work since it does not require you to do anything on your screen just your device turned on...google for "adb recovery s4" for detailed steps

Comment: And yes you can easily mirror the screen of your phone to your tv using and hdmi cable but still need to use the touch of the phone to click and etc